# best practices for mounting and unmounting shares

Tags: mount, unmounting, shared-folders

I am fairly new to Linux and have a general question. I have an Amazon AMI Linux EC2 instance that has a script that will copy files from many different remote computers to other computers, or to itself. The remote computers will mostly be windows but could also be Linux. Is it a good idea to mount the shared folder, copy the files, and then unmount it, or is it better to re-use shares and leave them mounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unmount them, if you want extra safety use the command *sync* before unmounting

Comment: ..or add `sync` to the mount options.